# How do I change rm command behavior to moving file to Trash by default in OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I want to achieve `rm /somepath/somefile` to move it to Trash instead of deleting it.

As well as `rm -rf /somefolder` and `rm *.txt` commands.

Answer (score 0):

I found some utilities to make it

`brew install trash`

so now `trash some_file`command does it.

and

a lot of helpful stuff [here](https://github.com/morgant/tools-osx)